# Consultar dados em um arquivo txt com python tkinter

Tags: python, query, tkinter, txt, tupla

Estou criando um sistema simples para consultar dados dos empregados armazenados em um arquivo `txt`.

```
def read_from_file(): 
    with open('dados.txt') as file:  
        for line in file:  
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            nome, matricula, supervisor, email, chave, local, centrodecusto = line.split('/') 
            base_dados[nome] = matricula, supervisor, email, chave, local, centrodecusto 

def write_to_file(nome_data, matricula_data, supervisor_data, email_data, chave_data, local_data, centrodecusto_data):
    with open('dados.txt') as file:   
        file.write('\n' + nome_data + '/' + matricula_data + '/' + supervisor_data + '/' + email_data + '/' + chave_data + '/' +  local_data + '/' + centrodecusto_data )

read_from_file() 
while True: 
    query_nome = simpledialog.askstring('Dados empregados', 'Digite o nome do empregado: ') 
    if query_nome in base_dados:
        result = base_dados[query_nome]
        messagebox.showinfo ('Answer',  
                             'teste' + query_nome + 'teste' + result + 'teste')  

root.mainloop()
```

Porém código me retorna o seguinte erro:

> File "path", line 24, in 
>       'teste' + query_nome + 'teste' + result + 'teste')   TypeError: must be str, not tuple

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: `result = base_dados[query_nome]` está retornando uma tupla.

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem de erro está sendo bem específica, você está concatenando uma tupla (tuple) em uma string, isso não é possível.

---

Para corrigir isso de forma bem pontual, você pode transforma a sua tupla em uma string, basta chamar a função `str` com a tupla como parâmetro:

```
messagebox.showinfo ('Answer','teste' + query_nome + 'teste' + str(result) + 'teste')
```

Dessa forma os dados da sua tupla são convertidos para string, sendo exibidos entre parenteses e separados por vírgula, algo semelhante a isso:

```
('000001', 'Daniel', 'daniel@email.com', '000001', 'São Paulo', '000001')
```

---

Abaixo o seu exemplo com as alterações para que os dados sejam exibidos sem gerar exceção:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox

base_dados = {}

def read_from_file():
    with open('dados.txt') as file:
        for line in file:  
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            nome, matricula, supervisor, email, chave, local, centrodecusto = line.split('/')
            base_dados[nome] = matricula, supervisor, email, chave, local, centrodecusto 

def write_to_file(nome_data, matricula_data, supervisor_data, email_data, chave_data, local_data, centrodecusto_data):
    with open('dados.txt') as file:
        file.write('\n' + nome_data + '/' + matricula_data + '/' + supervisor_data + '/' + email_data + '/' + chave_data + '/' +  local_data + '/' + centrodecusto_data )

root = tk.Tk()
read_from_file()

while True:
    query_nome = tk.simpledialog.askstring(parent=root, title='Dados empregados', prompt='Digite o nome do empregado: ')

    if not query_nome:
        break

    if query_nome in base_dados:
        result = base_dados[query_nome]
        messagebox.showinfo ('Answer',  
                            'Nome: ' + query_nome + ' - Dados: ' + str(result) + '.')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!